# Javascript: when is onbeforeunload triggered?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I'm adding a "confirm that you want to leave" dialogue to my website and am experiencing a strange behaviour of the `onbeforeunload` event.

The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) are pretty clear: If your page is about to be unloaded, this event is called. When your eventHandler returns a string, the user is asked for confirmation. Depending on the browser, the string may be displayed to him.

But in a small sample website, I noticed that `beforeunload` is only actually fired if the user somehow interacted with the website. This is my test setup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            $("#placeholder").text("website loaded")
            window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                return "Reloading the page will reset the survey!";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id='placeholder'></p>
</body>

</html>
```

When the window is loaded, the paragraph text is changed and an eventHandler for `beforeunload` is registered. If I load this in Firefox, the paragraph is immediately changed.

But if I close the tab or reload it, no confirmation is asked. The confirmation dialogue is only displayed if I have clicked in the website. Switching tabs back and forth is not enough, waiting for ca 10s is not enough.

The behaviour is the same in chrome.

Once I have clicked in the website, the confirmation is always asked. I can have another tab focused and close this example (by right-click and "close tab"), it asks for confirmation. Or another tab is focused and I try to close the browser, it asks for confirmation.

What is happening here, how can I make sure that the event is always fired before the site is unloaded ?

Here is a video:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried not wrapping onbeforeunload in onload and seeing if there is a difference?

Comment: just did. If I remove the onload, $ no longer works, so the paragraph is not changed. But the unloading behaviour is the same

Comment: You said it yourself: _"Depending on the browser, the string may be displayed to him."_ There is no guarantee. Apparently this browser decided that if a user didn't interact with the page, that there probably won't be a good reason for the page to block the user from going away.

Comment: No that's something different. The string can be the message displayed when it asks for confirmation - or not. The browser can also display its own message text. But if there is a handler, it should ask for confirmation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event fires, but the confirmation may not be shown. From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload):

> Note: To combat unwanted pop-ups, browsers may not display prompts
>   created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been
>   interacted with, or may even not display them at all.